# How to enable the dbnavigator.

Tags: delphi, tdbgrid

How to enable the dbNavigator which is by default disable when proram is executed. But its enable property is true? I have set the datasource property. What else do I need?

Comment: I did but its still disabled

Comment: It is still disabled I tried everything given in the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assign a dataSource to the `TDBNavigator.DataSource` property. Such a dataSource must be linked to a dataset by the `DataSet` property and that dataset must be opened. If all that is done, the navigator will work as expected.

Comment: The dataset is opened at thr run time and the data is displayed on the grid as well which is binded to the same datasource, but it doesnt help. Is there anything else I should do?

Comment: @AkshayJamwal Double-check that you've done it correctly. Put a button on your form with a breakpoint. Run your app, click the button. Check that `Navigator.DataSource` is correct, then check `Navigator.DataSource.DataSet`, then `Navigator.DataSource.DataSet.Active`, `Navigator.Enabled` ...

Comment: Actually Not really It still not working. I guess there is prob with the datasource. |
Navigator is enabled and the datasource.dataset is active. 
Please suggest any other workarround

Comment: @AkshayJamwal: is it possible for you to add a image of your form in run time (showing the navigator) and another one in designtime showing the Object Inspector, with the navigator selected?